# Problem with permissions in wp-content/plugins

Tags: plugins, security, permissions

I have a WP installation on my local machine and trying to get my hands dirty with plugins. I wish to clone a project from github which has this plugin code. However, i dont have the permissions inside plugins to do this as a normal user without su priveleges. (of course i can become root and do this but i dont think thats the way it should be).

Then by default the folders in a WP installation have group set to "tape", which appears strange to me.

What exactly should be the right permissions for the internal folders on a local WP installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing to do is check the WP docs themselves for correct file/folder permissions and how to change them, if needed: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

> Typically, all files should be owned by your user (ftp) account on
>   your web server, and should be writable by that account. On shared
>   hosts, files should never be owned by the web server process itself
>   (sometimes this is www, or apache, or nobody user).

Is "tape" a local user name? Or FTP name?

Depending on what kind of system you're using - a local install of apache, php and mysql - or a stack like Bitnami, XAMPP or MAMP, there may be slightly different owners and groups for folders and users.

Comment: No. "tape" is neither a local username nor an FTP name. As i mentioned, this WP installation is on my local machine running on localhost.

Comment: btw, i followed this post http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2200/cant-install-new-plugins-because-of-the-error-could-not-create-directory and edited my wp-config file.

Comment: Did the instructions in that other post work?

Comment: No. that was n t the solution actually.Right now i have 751 permission on my plugins folder. Seems to work.

Comment: OK, 755 is standard.

Comment: OK. so i temporarily changed the permissions in order to install a plugin and place some pdf files in wp-content/uploads. Then, the right thing is to put back the right permissions on everything.  <br>
`cd /var/www/html  
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; && find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`  <br>
Hope that helps someone.