# Can't Install/Upgrade Plugins Through WordPress

Tags: plugins, installation

I'm trying to download a plugin in wordpress, but keep geting the error "Unpacking the package…
Could not create directory.".

I'm using mac

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install new plugins because of the error "Could not create directory"](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2200/cant-install-new-plugins-because-of-the-error-could-not-create-directory)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a file permissions issue.  In a nutshell, this error means that your website cannot write/add/delete files in the plugins folder on your webserver.

To fix this you need to update your file permissions for the WordPress install on your server.  You will need SSH access to your server with the user that has write permissions.

**DO NOTE**:  If you have never changed file permissions on a server before and are not sure how to do it, I would definitely contact your host and have them do this for you.  Messing around in the command line can really screw things up if you do something wrong (been there, done that).

**ASSUMING YOU'RE ON A LINUX SERVER**: Once you SSH into your server, you can run these 2 commands to update all the permissions to their proper (and secure) settings.

`find /path/to/your/wordpress/install/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

`find /path/to/your/wordpress/install/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

This will change all of the `files` on your wordpress install to 755 and all of the `folders` on your install to 644.  That should allow you to do anything you need to from the WordPress admin.

SOURCE: http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_Permissions

Answer (score 0):

That's a permissions issue. Either you need to allow any user to write to your /wp-content/plugins directory or you need to change the ownership of the plugins directory to the same as the web server.
If that sounds confusing, the easy way is just to download the plugin zip package, unzip it and put it in your /wp-content/plugins/ directory.  Once you've copied it, it's installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give write permissions to the relevant directories. Ideally, you should do it only for the relevant file or folder and then revert the permissions back so as to not leave your site vulnerable.

You can fix this using the following commands from the command line (assuming that you are in the Wordpress root folder):

```
# cd wp-content
# chmod -R a+w plugins
# chmod -R a+w themes
# chmod -R a+w upgrade
```

The safest solution is to add apache (or your web server user) to the same group as the owner of the Wordpress installation and change all group permissions to writeable.